# How can I use jQuery to add a class based on the filename?

Tags: jquery, html, class, navigation, nav

I am designing a website that has the same navigation throughout, but I wish to highlight the current page in the navigation.

For this purpose, I tried using this jQuery code...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var $filename = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
 var $element = $('#' + $filename);
 $($element).addClass('active');
 });
});
```

..on this HTML code (I gave each a different id as I wasn't sure which would work)...

```
<nav class="closed">
 <a id="index" href="#">Home</a>
 <a id="index.php" href="#">About</a>
 <a id="/index.php" href="#">Forum</a>
 <a id="\index.php" href="#">Get involved</a>
</nav>
```

However, I cannot seem to get this code to work. How can I add a class to an element with a specific id based on the current URL/filename?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
var $element = $('#' + $filename);
$($element).addClass('active');
```

use

```
$('#' + $filename).addClass('active');
```

And instead of document.ready, use jQuery.
Whole code:

```
$(function() {
    var filename = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    var element = $('#' + $filename);
    $(element).addClass('active');
});
```

Or even shorter, but harder to debug:

```
$(function() {
    $('#' + (window.location.pathname.split('/').pop())).addClass('active');
});
```

Remember that the method you are using is vunerable for errors if user comes with, for example, index.php?id=2. It would be wise to use:

```
var filename = (window.location.pathname.split('/').pop()).split('?')[0];
```

Comment: you're still going to have to escape special characters in the selector

Comment: @Kamil So what value would your alternative suggestion return? Would it return `index`, `index.php` or something else?